# Create table from https .csv with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new with python but i'm trying to get data from an API which later on I want to enter in our sql database.
I have the beginning of the code which gives me a 200 status code. I used this code;

```py
url = "https://api.squeezely.tech/v1/reporting/events"

fields = {
        "from" : "2020-01-01" , 
        "to" : "2026-01-01",
        "custom_fields" : "no"}

json=json.dumps(fields)

headers={"X-AUTH-ACCOUNT" :"our account",
         "X-AUTH-APIKEY" :"our key",
         "Content-Type" : "application/json",
         "charset" : "UTF-8",
         "allow_redirects" : "false"}

response = requests.post(url, json=fields, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

The status code i get is 200 and the response.text i get is
`{"success":true,"url":"https: xxxx .csv"}`

I tried reading the https . csv url with pandas;

```py
response = requests.post(url, json=fields, headers=headers)
data = pd.read_csv(response)
Print(data)
```

But this gave the following error;

> "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class'requests.models.Response'>"

Can someone help me with how I should read the response in order to get a table

Comment: please RTFM what `post()` returns and how to get payload from it.

Comment: That looks like a JSON response that contains a URL to a CSV file. So you should probably be extracting the URL and reading this into the dataframe...

Comment: `response.text`, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response` in the question looks like a JSON response that contains a URL to a CSV file which is, presumably, the data that you are after...

So here is how you can read the CSV data into a pandas DataFrame (assuming that this is your intention):

```py
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import io

json_data = {"success":true,"url":"https://xxxx.csv"}

csv_url = json_data['url']

# download CSV data 
new_response = requests.get(csv_url)

# read CSV data into pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(new_response.text))

print(df)
```

I called it `new_response` so as to differentiate from the original response.

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed able to get the information from the CSV file!